# How run BERT in production?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, bert-language-model

I've created a BERT model. What are the ways to do the deployment of this model? Is it possible to use it with Spark, Hadoop or Docker?

Comment: Why does "production" matter? How are you currently running it? What's wrong with that way?

Comment: @cricket_007 Because as a rule, models are developed not for fun but for some business purposes. "production" means to parallelize computation and creat APIs. Currently, I don't run it at all.

Comment: If module are currently not used, then I would suggest focusing on best practices of storing, versioning, managing, securing, upgrading them, etc. Then figure out some pipeline in which they run, whether that be one machine, or several. The short answer is that 1) Hadoop is not required. 2) Docker is probably too broad to learn just for this single task 3) Spark should be able to use the models, but maybe not out of the box (refer tensorflow on Spark)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your comment. Just to make sure we on the same page. I have a BERT model that takes CSV files as input (text) and it outputs text with some predictions (restored punctuation in this text). The model works pretty fast on GPU, but I run it as a Python (PyTorch) script. For example, if I have 100 GPU how can I parallelize computation? I cannot use Spark with it because Spark doesn't include PyTorch. Is Docker my option here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "Spark does not include PyTorch". You can bundle it in your Spark environment.